# How to alter this script to add another condition

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this piece of code which has been working great for me, however, I need a minor alteration to it and don't know how to proceed.

I would like for 'Multiple Use' to be added as another condition, alongside 'Yes' for the `onEdit()` to work.

```
function numberToLetter(number){
  // converts the column number to a letter
  var temp = "";
  var letter = "";
  while (number > 0){
    temp = (number - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    number = (number - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function obtainFirstBlankRow() {  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Aug2019');
  // search for first blank row
  var col = sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var vals = col.getValues();
  var count = 0;

  while (vals[count][0] != "") {
    count++;
  }
  return count + 1;
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (ss.getName() == 'ProspectiveSites' && e.range.getColumn() == 26) {

    if (e.range.getValue() != 'Yes'){
      Logger.log('test');
      return;
    }

    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ProspectiveSites');
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Aug2019');

    //Logger.log('O' + e.getRow() + ':O' + e.getRow());
    Logger.log(e);
    Logger.log(e.range.getValue());
    var cell15 = sourceSheet.getRange('O' + e.range.getRow() + ':O' + e.range.getRow()).getValue();
    var cell24 = sourceSheet.getRange('X' + e.range.getRow() + ':X' + e.range.getRow()).getValue();
    Logger.log(cell15);
    Logger.log(cell24);

    var row = obtainFirstBlankRow();    
    targetSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(cell15);
    targetSheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(cell24);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

What stops you from adding another condition for the `if` statement? Please, take some time to research JS documentation, it will greatly help you in the long run (see useful links after the sample).

**Modifications**

This modification assumes that you need to exit if **value is not equal to "Multiple use" and not equal to "Yes"**. Also, note that there are a few additional changes made for optimization purposes (I changed all comparison operators to strict as well).

**Sample**

```
/**
 * onEdit simple trigger;
 * @param {Object} event object;
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var actS = ss.getActiveSheet(); //active sheet === source sheet;

  //access event object params;
  var range  = e.range;
  var row    = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var value  = range.getValue();

  if (actS.getName()==='ProspectiveSites' && column===26) {

    if (value!=='Yes'&&value!=='Multiple Use') {
      Logger.log('test');
      return;
    }

    var augS = ss.getSheetByName('Aug2019'); //target sheet;

    var cell15val = actS.getRange('O'+row+':O'+row).getValue();
    var cell24val = actS.getRange('X'+row+':X'+row).getValue();

    var rowBlank = obtainFirstBlankRow();
    var target = augS.getRange(rowBlank,1,1,2); //idx, first col, 1 row, 2 cols;
        target.setValues([[ cell15val , cell24val ]]);
  }
}
```

**Useful links**

1. `if..else` statement [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) on MDN;
2. Comparison operators [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) on MDN;
3. `getRange()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer));
4. `setValues()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I am really new to using apps script and still learning. I did try to add the condition to the If statement but obviously got the wrong syntax. When I try and run your sample I get this error; ReferenceError: "as" is not defined. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: Sorry, mistyped reference to Spreadsheet [ofc it should be `ss`]!

Comment: ok, I checked it again and now receive this; Execution failed: ReferenceError: "obtainFirstBlankRow" is not defined. (line 27, file "Code") [0.749 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Have you by any chance replaced all of the code with only this function? You obviously should not, `obtainFirstBlankRow` is one of the dependencies in your `onEdit` trigger

Comment: yes, I did do you. I have not tried to add just your addition of the If statement, making that line in my original script read; if (e.range.getValue() != 'Yes'&&value!=='Multiple Use'){. This now only works for the Yes portion and now for Multiple Use, and returns this error; ReferenceError: "value" is not defined. (line 32, file "Code") [0.852 seconds total runtime]

Comment: You will be better off replacing the whole `onEdit()` function (it is heavily optimized). The only way you could've recieved a `ReferenceError` the second time is if the function `obtainFirstBlankRow` wasn't defined (and since it was defined previously, I assumed you replaced everything with the updated function. Please, don't just copy and paste parts of the code if you don't know what is going on (the `value` variable in your original code is never defined prior to being called in `if` statement, thus the error)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197088/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-user10637952).